# Tracking user read/unread of a link/document in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using solr to index reports from DB. I am successful in doing that. However, I also need to track user activity to report whether a document has been read by the user or not. I am aware that Solr is not built to index/keep track user activity, but is there a good approach going about this ?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

No, as you say there is no support for this in Solr. From a Solr perspective it’s more related to how you build you web-application. I would recommend you to ask yourself this:

***When tracking the reading statistics of my users do I need to index that information into Solr too?***

The answer to this question depends on if you need to the information to facet, search or use it in the relevance model. Say for example you want to have a facet that allows your users to filter on read or unread documents then of course you need to index this into Solr.

If you only want to present whether or not a document has been read or not (in the web interface) you might as well store this information inside a SQL database fetching it when presenting the results.